# Comparing text columns to different data types

Tags: mysql

MySQL allows me to do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text_field = 75
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text_field < 14.67
```

I would like to know what are the implications of doing that.
Will MySQL make a table full scan to convert the text values?
Is this operation performatic?

My problem is that I have a table that stores dynamic details and the values are always stored in a text column, regardless of its type. Would it be better if I create a specific column for each possible data type?

Comment: You can run EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text_field = 75 to see how MySQL executes the query.  For large numbers of rows you'd probably be better off creating separate columns for text, integer, decimal, etc. value.

Comment: The EXPLAIN results when comparing text=text and text=integer are equal.